# Update an Android Widget when the screen is turned ON

Tags: android, events, android-widget

The question is simple as it seems.

The Android Widget works as a charm, everything is OK.

I just want the widget content **to be updated** *when (in the right moment)* **the user turn on its device screen**.

I can't find a hint for this in internet nor the documentation. This means that I'm clearly overlooking something easy and important.

## UPDATE

Thanks for the answer of Murtaza, seems perfect, but for some reason isn't working.
My widget has already a receiver, so i added the suggested intent filter:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyWidget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Inside the widget class i overriden the suggested function:

```
@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
      playNotification(context);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
      playNotification(context);
    }
 }
```

The playNotification() plays an alarm. It works properly inside the widget. But when I switch the screen ON and OFF, nothing happens.

## UPDATE II - A working widget in Android

I post the whole code of the widget for who need it.

```
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;


/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        playNotification(context, true);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        playNotification(context, true);
    }
}

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {
    String widgetText = "";

    playNotification(context, true);

    widgetText += " DATE:" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getHours() + ":" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes();
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.mywidget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

public static void playNotification(Context context, boolean alarm) {

    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if (alarm) notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
        if (!r.isPlaying())
            r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## ANDROID MANIFEST

This is what you need to add to the manifest to have a working widget on Android. More, the filters I would like to make work.

```
   <receiver android:name=".MYWidget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/mywidget_info" />
    </receiver>
```

PLEASE NOTE THAT the code works. Everything except what concern my question: "Update an Android Widget when the screen is turned ON"

Comment: maybe that´s what You´re looking for: https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Comment: It doens't help, my question is about widgets, they don't have onPause() onResume life cycle.

Comment: I know, but the point is to see the example of the BroadcastReceiver. With this receiver You know if the screen is turned on or off. How do You have to update Your widget is another thing. When the screen goes on, You will be notified by the receiver and then You can update Your widget.The answer from Murtaza is correct.

Comment: from inside the receiver in the code below, You have to do the work or call a method from another class which updates Your widget.

Comment: Opiatefuchs thank you for answering the question "how to notice when the device screen is turned on", that is clear. But my question is: "how to update the widget when the screen is turned on".
The code below would be useful if it would work in a widget, but it doesn't. Why should I handle the broadcast receiver elsewhere if the widget already work as a receiver? Maybe because a widget handles JUST the APPWIDGET_UPDATE action? What do you think?
Did you see my update? Is there a reason why that code Murtaza suggested doesn't work inside a widget?

Comment: Yes You´re wright. The APPWIDGET_UPDATE is just handled by the widget. It will not automatically updated if the screen turns on. BroadCastReceivers are usefull when You want to know something about an executed action. But every action has to be registered, so like turning screen on or off, or start the phone if it is off.

Comment: I think Your playNotification(); method is inside the receiver, right? What You can do is, create a class where You put this method inside as a public method. So You can call this from inside every other class.

Comment: Ok, I put the whole code with the playNotification which as I said is called inside the widget to perform a general action (a something). It is an Android Widget. Hope this can help.

Comment: Ok, but what I meant was, to make an external class where You put the playNotification() inside. Then You can call it from Your widget AND your BroadcastReceiver for turning on the screen. That´s important, otherwise it will not work. Also, delete those SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF intent filtzers from Your widget receiver, they will have no effect on this receiver. I think it will be the best way, if You can send me Your code if it is ok, then I can check all and give You a solution. opiatefuchs@gmail.com

Comment: Wow thank you for being so kind. So you're telling me that SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF intent filters simply have no effect? So that is the problem. Is it documented anywhere that the widget receiver work just with a subset of filters? In that case I need to make a broadcast receiver somewhere else indeed, which is crazy as many Android things I suppose.

Comment: In the Appwidget Provider, they will have no effect. That´s the point, You need to do an new BroadcastReceiver class only with this filters...and yes, many things are crazy in android..but wait if You develop for IOS :)....then YOU going crazy :)

Comment: :) I'm not even trying, I am playing with it don't want it to become a i-pain!! Thank you anyway. I'll try your way as soon as I have some free time again and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Broadcast Receiver for that.

Add these permissions in your Manifest.xml

```
 <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_ON"></action>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
           //update your widget.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This code sounded perfect, but inserting it in my widget it doesn't work.

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
This will work.

Answer (score 0):

The question turns into a new one, so I want to show some example. Your question now is, how to update the widget from inside all other classes. As I suspect, Your playNotification(); method is inside the receiver of Your widget. What You have to do is, make an extra class with Your playNotification() method as public , so You can call it from every other class. Look this example, based on the answer from Murtaza and Your update:

### create an extra class:

```
 public class NotificationHelper{
 private Context mContext;


 //make a constructor and set Context or other objects/values if You need it
  public NotificationHelper(Context ctx){

     mContext = ctx;
  }


  public void playNotification(){

    //do Your stuff here inside
  }

}
```

With this public class, You can do Your stuff from anywhere else. For example inside Your AppWidget Receiver or Your BroadCastReceiver that will be fired if the screen goes on or off:

```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
     NotificationHelper mHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
     mHelper.playNotification();
   } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
     NotificationHelper mHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
     mHelper.playNotification();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Opiafechus I also correct a mistake on the manifest (android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON instead of ACTION_SCREEN_ON) and applied this code you suggest (is the same I wrote on yesterday's update)
 but it doesn't work, i.e., the widget doesn't call playNotification() when screen is turned on.

Comment: can You please post Your updatet code? I need to see the class where You call playNotification , Your Receivers and Your full manifest....